# Central Limit Theorem for Multinomial Distribution

Tags: central-limit-theorem, characteristic-functions, multinomial-distribution

I am trying to apply CLT for multinomial distribution in the following way.

Suppose $v=(v_{1}\ldots v_{N})$ is multinomial random vector, so $v\sim M(n,p), p=(p_{1}\ldots p_{N})$.

Its characteristic function has the form:

$\psi_{v}(t)=(\sum_{j=1}^Np_{j}e^{it_{j}})^n$

Then we consider:

$v^{*}=\frac{v}{\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt{n}p$

Under this linear transformation the characteristic function becomes:

$\psi_{v^*}(t)=(\sum_{j=1}^Np_{j}e^{\frac{it_{j}}{\sqrt{n}}})^ne^{-\sqrt{n}i\sum_{j=1}^Np_{j}t_{j}}$

Taking log yields:

$\ln(\psi_{v^*}(t))=n\cdot \ln(\sum_{j=1}^Np_{j}e^{\frac{it_{j}}{\sqrt{n}}})-\sqrt{n}i\sum_{j=1}^Np_{j}t_{j}$

Then taking the limit and transforming it to $\frac{0}{0}$ gives:

$\lim_\limits{{n\to\infty}} \ln(\psi_{v^*}(t))=lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(\sum_{j=1}^Np_{j}e^{\frac{it_{j}}{\sqrt{n}}})-\frac{i\sum_{j=1}^Np_{j}t_{j}}{\sqrt{n}}}{n^{-1}}$

Using l'Hospital rule and making some straightforward transformations I achieve:

$\lim_\limits{{n\to\infty}}\ln(\psi_{v^*}(t))=\frac{i\sqrt{n}}{2}\sum_{j=1}^Np_{j}t_{j}(e^{\frac{it_{j}}{\sqrt{n}}}-1)$

Transfering $\sqrt{n}$ to denominator and using l'Hospital rule again I finally get:

$\lim_\limits{{n\to\infty}}\psi_{v^*}(t)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^Np_{j}t_{j}^2}$

It is the characteristic function of a multivariate normal distribution with zero covariances and variances equal to $p_{j}$. **However this answer is wrong** as true covariance matrix has the form $\Sigma_{ij}=p_{i}(1-p_{i})$ if $i=j$ and $\Sigma_{ij}=-p_{i}p_{i}$ otherwise.

Please help me figure out where I am wrong.

Comment: You seem to mix $n$ and $N$. Are they the same?

Comment: They are not, because n is the number of trials while N represents the number of possible outcomes. For example imagine elections with 100 voters and 3 candidates. Each voter votes for candidate $i$ with probability $p_{i}$. Then we get multinomial distribution where $v_{i}$ represents number of votes for candidate $i$ and N=3 while n=100

Comment: Why not use proper tools, say, the (ultra well known) limited expansions of $\exp$ and $\log$? Note that $$e^x=1+x+x^2/2+o(x^2)$$ when $x\to0$ hence 
$$\sum_jp_{j}e^{it_{j}/\sqrt{n}}=1+ia/\sqrt{n}-b/(2n)+o(1/n)$$ where $$a=\sum_jp_jt_j\qquad b=\sum_jp_jt_j^2$$
Furthermore, $$\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+o(x^2)$$ when $x\to0$ hence $$\ln\left(\sum_jp_{j}e^{it_{j}/\sqrt{n}}\right)=ia/\sqrt{n}-b/(2n)+a^2/(2n)+o(1/n)$$ which implies $$\ln\psi_{v^*}(t)\to-(b-a^2)/2$$ Finally, your result holds since $$b-a^2=\sum_jp_j(1-p_j)t_j^2-\sum_{j\ne k}p_jp_kt_jt_k$$

Comment: Thank you very much! It answers my question and also highlights useful tool for me!

Comment: @Bogdan funny, I ended up at this question because I tried to model voters too. What did you find out?